# How to use "as" or "how"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, conjunctions

I'm confused to use "as" and "how", for instance

*As you see below, this picture represents for me great emotional value*

or

*How you see below, this picture represents for me great emotional value*

Comment: Always As.. you would only start a sentence with How if it's a question. Also your word order should be "this picture represents great emotional value for me" unless you put commas in: "this picture represents, for me, great emotional value".

Comment: Thanks man, about commas, I'm still learning how to use... Is it right? or  Should I use "as"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How" is used often to make a question asking about the way something happen.

> How does this watch work?
>
> How can I go there?

And sometimes as a subordinated clause

> I don't know how to go there

*How* is also used to ask about or acknowledge the amount/size or degree of something

> How big is it?
>
> How difficult it is to buy a ticket.

*How* can also be used to ask the opinions of others about something

> How was the film.

=======================

"As" has many usages, it is generally used for making comparison especially when two things match

> He is as old as you.

As a proposition "As" may be used to say what job, duty, appearance, role someone or something has

> As a parent, you should protect your children
>
> A flat stone was used as a table

also to say **in the way** that something happens or someone says

> The money was repaid, as promised
>
> Do as I say

It is also used to give reasons

> As it was getting late, I turned around to start for home

==============================

Then remember, when you are using "How" you usually ask about or inform the way something happen but when you use "As", there are two concepts or things that match or correspond

Comment: I liked of example `Do as I say`. If I use "how", it'd give another meaning to the sentence, right?

Comment: @ThMoraes Yes then, it would probably mean *speak in the way I speak* or "speak like me", but using "as" means "do in the way I tell you"

Answer (score 2):

In some languages both *as* and *how* are expressed by the same word. German comes to mind ("wie").

In order to distinguish between the two, you need to analyze what role the word has in the sentence:

If it is a **question**, use *how*:

> How far is it?
>   How do you do?

Even if the question is rhetorical or basically an exclamation:

> How nice of you!

If you need a **conjunction**, that is if you connect two phrases, sentences or clauses, use *as*:

> As the sun rose (part 1), the day grew warmer (part 2).
>   As you can see in this diagram (part 1), sales increased substantially in 2011(part 2).
>   As he had already left (part 1), he didn't hear John's story (part 2).

Even more common is the correlative construction *as ... as*:

> He's as tall as his mother now.